# Reordering MFC control IDs automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, resources

I've got a pretty old MFC application that's been touched by many people over the years (most of them probably not even CS guys) and it follows, what I like to call the "anarchy design pattern."

Anyway, one of the dialogs has a series of 56 vertical sliders and check boxes. However, there are additional sliders and checkboxes on the dialog as shown below.

[image]

Now, the problem is that the additional sliders and checkboxes take on IDs that are in sequence with the slider/checkbox series of the dialog. My task is to add more sliders and checkboxes to the series (in the blank space in the Slider Control group box) Unfortunately, since `IDC_SLIDER57` through `IDC_SLIDER61` are already in the dialog (same goes for the checkboxes), existing code, such as the snippet below will break:

```
pVSlider = (CSliderCtrl *)GetDlgItem(IDC_SLIDER1+i);
```

Is there a better way to modify the resource file without doing it manually? I've seen a third party tool called [ResOrg](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/resorg/index.html) that looks like it'll help do what I want, but the software is a bit pricey, especially since I'll only use it once. I guess I can give the demo a try, but the limitations might restrict me.

FYI, I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 (yes...I know, don't laugh, it's being forced upon me).

Comment: Visual C++ 6.0 was a classic, I won't laugh I promise. It's not hard to renumber resource IDs manually if you leave enough empty space so that you're only changing one digit. For example if `IDC_SLIDER57` is 234 and `IDC_SLIDER61` is 238, just change the first digit from 2 to 3 and you've freed up IDs 234-333.

Comment: Well yeah, but I'd also like the names to be consistent, and that causes an issue because it yells at me that the symbol already exists elsewhere

Comment: You can reserve spots for the sliders, say from 4000 to 5000 with different names `#define IDC_SLIDER_X1 4001` Do this manually otherwise dialog editor tries to take control of these constants (and backup your project, it all goes wrong if you touch the wrong thing) See also this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want updated UI look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
pVSlider = (CSliderCtrl *)GetDlgItem(IDC_SLIDER1+i);
```

you could write:

```
pVSlider = (CSliderCtrl *)GetDlgItem(GetSliderID(i));
```

where `GetSlider` is a function that returns the id of slider number i.

**GetSlider function**

```
int GetSliderID(int nslider)
{
  static int sliderids[] = {IDC_SLIDER1, IDC_SLIDER2, IDC_SLIDER3, .... IDC_SLIDERn};
  ASSERT(nslider < _countof(sliderids));
  return sliderids[nslider];    
}
```

With this method the `IDC_SLIDERn` symbols dont need to have sequential values.